# NavigationBar color stays black in dark mode regardless of color specified

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-components-android

I am currently in the process of switching to the light navigation bar API 27+. I changed it slightly so it matches my bottom navigation. However, when switching to dark mode, it ignores the color I set.

```xml
// themes-v27.xml
<style name="Theme.Planner.DayNight.LightNavigationBar" parent="Theme.Planner">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigation_bar</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">@bool/isDayMode</item>
</style>
```

```xml
// colors.xml
<resources>
    <color name="navigation_bar">@color/grey_50</color>
</resources>
```

```xml
// colors.xml (night)
<resources>
    <color name="navigation_bar">@color/planner_red</color> <!-- using red for demonstration -->
</resources>
```

```xml
// BottomNav
<style name="Widget.Planner.BottomNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.Planner.BottomNavigationView</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.Planner.BottomNavigationView" parent="">
    <item name="backgroundTint">?colorSurface</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">?colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you place your XML code here for this bar?

Comment: added the theme for the bottom nav bar, is this what you mean?

Comment: No, not the Theme. I would like to see the layout xml of that nav bar.